How to build gcc10 from source in Amazon Linux 2023? Getting version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found
I am trying to install the NVIDIA driver and Cuda toolkit but it expects gcc10. Using p2.xlarge which has Tesla k80. And Tesla k80 supports Cuda toolkit 11.4 (https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/). Then from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version, it says that Cuda toolkit 11.4 requires gcc10.
And AWS documentation says Amazon Linux 2023 does not support EPEL (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/compare-with-al2.html#epel)
So I tried to build it from the source and took the steps below.
// Download source
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-10.5.0/gcc-10.5.0.tar.gz

// extract files
tar -xf gcc-10.5.0.tar.gz

// installing gcc as configure expects some c compiler
// below command will install gcc11, which I don't want
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

// download prerequisites
./contrib/download_prerequisites

// create make file using configure
mkdir objdir
cd ../objdir
$PWD/../gcc-10.5.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/GCC-10.5.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib

// no building. this step gives error
make

Make command gives below error
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/python'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
true "AR_FLAGS=rc" "CC_FOR_BUILD=gcc" "CC_FOR_TARGET=/home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/" "CFLAGS=-g -O2" "CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE" "CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=-g -O2" "CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-g -O2" "INSTALL=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_DATA=/usr/bin/install -c -m 644" "INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/install -c" "LDFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS=-g -O2" "LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-g -O2" "MAKE=make" "MAKEINFO=/home/ec2-user/gcc-10.5.0/missing makeinfo --split-size=5000000 --split-size=5000000 --split-size=5000000   " "SHELL=/bin/sh" "RUNTESTFLAGS=" "exec_prefix=/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0" "infodir=/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/share/info" "libdir=/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/lib" "includedir=/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/include" "prefix=/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0" "tooldir=/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" "gxx_include_dir=/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/include/c++/10.5.0" "AR=ar" "AS=/home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/as" "LD=/home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/collect-ld" "RANLIB=ranlib" "NM=/home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/nm" "NM_FOR_BUILD=" "NM_FOR_TARGET=nm" "DESTDIR=" "WERROR=" DO=all multi-do # make
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp'
make  all-recursive
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp'
Making all in testsuite
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp/testsuite'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp/testsuite'
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp'
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile /home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/ -B/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include   -fno-checking -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp  -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/config/linux/x86 -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/config/linux -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/config/posix -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/../include  -Wall -Werror -ftls-model=initial-exec -DUSING_INITIAL_EXEC_TLS -Wc,-pthread  -g -O2 -MT alloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/alloc.Tpo -c -o alloc.lo /home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/alloc.c
libtool: compile:  /home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/ -B/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/ec2-user/GCC-10.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include -fno-checking -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/config/linux/x86 -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/config/linux -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/config/posix -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp -I/home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/../include -Wall -Werror -ftls-model=initial-exec -pthread -DUSING_INITIAL_EXEC_TLS -g -O2 -MT alloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/alloc.Tpo -c /home/ec2-user/objdir/../gcc-10.5.0/libgomp/alloc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/alloc.o
/home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/cc1: /home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/ec2-user/objdir/./gcc/cc1)
make[5]: *** [Makefile:827: alloc.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1057: all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:648: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgomp'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:26932: all-stage1-target-libgomp] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:28732: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ec2-user/objdir'
make: *** [Makefile:1020: all] Error 2


What is the output of ldd --version?
